# How do I insert into a table a mixed query

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, insert

I'm trying to perform a complex issue,
I have a query structured like this:

```
Select 
       (
        SELECT     a.CD_MAD, b.* FROM 
                                  (
                                   SELECT '0' & [CD_SOC] & [CT_OPR] & [CD_MVT] & [CT_MVT] & [CD_RGL_FIN] & [CD_MODEPAIE] AS p, 
                                          [table3].CD_MAD FROM table3
                                  )  AS a 
        RIGHT JOIN (
                    SELECT trim([CODECIE]) & trim([TPOPER]) & trim([MVNT]) & trim([TPMVNT]) & trim([MODEPAIE]) & trim([MODEPAIE1]) AS p, 
                           tbl1.CODEENR, tbl1.CODECIE, tbl1.TPOPER, tbl1.MVNT,
                           tbl1.TPMVNT, tbl1.DTCOMPT, tbl1.DTDEBEF, tbl1.SIGNE,
                           tbl1.TTTCF, tbl1.TTTCG, tbl1.DEVISEF, tbl1.DEVISEG,
                           tbl1.CODEPDT, tbl1.NOCTR, tbl1.NOPIECE, tbl1.CATMIN, 
                           tbl1.NOCPT, tbl1.MODEPAIE, tbl1.THTF, tbl1.THTG, 
                           tbl1.TAXE_F, tbl1.TAXE_G, tbl1.FRAC, tbl1.APPORT, 
                           tbl1.VENDEUR, tbl1.MODEPAIE1, tbl1.TPEVNT, 
                           tbl1.FAITGEN, tbl1.DTSURV, tbl1.DURPR, tbl1.NOPIECE1,
                           tbl1.ANNEE, tbl1.MNTCOMCO, tbl1.MNTCOMAP, tbl1.ID 
                   FROM    tbl1
                  )  AS b ON b.p=a.p
        );
```

this  query basically creates a join between two subsets of two existing tables  without passing trough  the building of temporary tables(which is my aim!); that query works just fine.
but now I'd like to insert the query's results into a table;
i'd already tried the "insert into" statement but it seems to fail; in particular it seems that the alias "a" and "b" that i'v used to create the query aren't recognized when performing the insert into statement.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: can you please add the INSERT SQL in a more readable format, and what is the exact error you are encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (user, column1, column2) 
SELECT      a.CD_MAD, b.* FROM 
                               (
                                SELECT '0' & [CD_SOC] & [CT_OPR] & [CD_MVT] & [CT_MVT] & [CD_RGL_FIN] & [CD_MODEPAIE] AS p, 
                                       [table3].CD_MAD FROM table3
                               )  AS a 
RIGHT JOIN (
            SELECT trim([CODECIE]) & trim([TPOPER]) & trim([MVNT]) & trim([TPMVNT]) & trim([MODEPAIE]) & trim([MODEPAIE1]) AS p, 
                   tbl1.CODEENR, tbl1.CODECIE, tbl1.TPOPER, tbl1.MVNT,
                   tbl1.TPMVNT, tbl1.DTCOMPT, tbl1.DTDEBEF, tbl1.SIGNE,
                   tbl1.TTTCF, tbl1.TTTCG, tbl1.DEVISEF, tbl1.DEVISEG,
                   tbl1.CODEPDT, tbl1.NOCTR, tbl1.NOPIECE, tbl1.CATMIN, 
                   tbl1.NOCPT, tbl1.MODEPAIE, tbl1.THTF, tbl1.THTG, 
                   tbl1.TAXE_F, tbl1.TAXE_G, tbl1.FRAC, tbl1.APPORT, 
                   tbl1.VENDEUR, tbl1.MODEPAIE1, tbl1.TPEVNT, 
                   tbl1.FAITGEN, tbl1.DTSURV, tbl1.DURPR, tbl1.NOPIECE1,
                   tbl1.ANNEE, tbl1.MNTCOMCO, tbl1.MNTCOMAP, tbl1.ID 
             FROM  tbl1
              )  AS b ON b.p=a.p;
```

Basically gettin rid of the first bracket and select should help